# Deploying Visual Studio Web Stie to IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-7, web-config, web-deployment, web.config-transform

I am new to Visual Studio 2012 so I am still learning how everything works.  I have read threads over and over on how to deploy using the one-click publish method in Visual Studio to IIS.  I have tried over and over and I am still having trouble getting my site up.  I am currently very confused on how to configure my web.config files to publish to IIS.

What exactly should change or be added to be able to publish?  I have tried reading up on web.config transformation files. In a Web application it creates them for you (web.config.release & web.config.debug) It does not do this for you with a Web Site.

Please point me in the direction of a tutorial on how to do this and better understand deployment techniques.

Answer (score 0):

WebDeploy/MSDeploy is the best way to deploy an ASP.NET website in my opinion.  Read this post to see how it works.

https://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/25/the-anatomy-of-a-webdeploy-package/

The publish from VS is limited.  Use the commandline or TFS or anything else.